# nginx-apache-wordpress: setup apache/wordpress under subdirectory and behind nginx

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I had developed a Rails app and was happy with it, but I was asked to setup Wordpress under subdirectory `/wp`. After some unhappy hours of trying to make nginx-to-apache proxying work, I gave up copying code from shitty guides and wrote some very short and clear config:

```
location @wp {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location ~ ^/wp(/|$) {
  root /home/apache/www;
  rewrite ^/wp/?$ / break;
  rewrite ^/wp/(.*) /$1 break;
  try_files $uri @wp;
}
```

It solved most of problems I've had experienced, but it won't work for an obvious reason: 
Wordpress generates `<real_ip>:8080/<url>` links and that is not just ugly (I can live with it), but links don't work since Apache listens on localhost only.
How can I tell Apache or Wordpress (or what header should I proxy with Nginx) to make links look like `<real_ip>/wp/<url>`? Or is my setup faulty by design? I would appreciate any solution or hint, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my configuration for nginx, which runs a Rails app at the main root, and a WordPress blog under a subdirectory.  Perhaps try this?

```
server {
  listen <ip-address>:80;
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
  break;
}

server {
  listen <ip-address>:80;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  root   /www/domain.com/public_html/current/public;

  access_log /www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log /www/domain.com/logs/error.log;

  location ^~ /blog {
    root /www/domain.com/blog/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        if ($uri !~ "^/images/") {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        }
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/domain.com/blog/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of your included `/etc/nginx/fascgi_params`file?  I really can't get it to work with this.